# Вывод нужного текста для каждого дня в году

Tags: android

Я хочу сравнить несколько дат с текущей. Приложение должно вывести на экран текст для каждого дня свое.

```
   TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    String valid_until = "7/3";
    String valid_until1 = "8/3";
    String valid_until2 = "9/3";
    String valid_until3 = "10/3";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
    Date strDate = null;
    Date strDate1 = null;
    Date strDate2 = null;
    Date strDate3 = null;


    try {
        strDate = sdf.parse(valid_until);
        strDate1 = sdf.parse(valid_until1);
        strDate2 = sdf.parse(valid_until2);
        strDate3 = sdf.parse(valid_until3);


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (new Date() == (strDate)) {
        textView.setText("Сегодня 7 марта");
    }
    if (new Date() == (strDate1)) {
        textView.setText("Сегодня 8 марта");
    }
    if (new Date() == (strDate2)) {
        textView.setText("Сегодня 9 марта");
    }
    if (new Date() == (strDate3)) {
        textView.setText("Сегодня 10 марта");
    }
```

Comment: В чем вопрос? И зачем столько ```if'ов```? Почему нельзя просто взять из текущей даты день недели и вывести его ? Ну и в догонку, не одно из условий не сработает хотя бы потому, что оператор ```==``` сравнивает ссылки на объекты, а не сами объекты. Но это не единственный случай почему условия не сработают.

Comment: @temq Можете показать как правильнее будет ? ... Я навичок и не особо разбираюсь... Мне нужно сравнить все 365  дней с текущей датой и вывести для каждого дня разные тексты.

Comment: Для сравнения объектов используйте `object1.equals(object2)`.

Comment: Вам нужно писать именно эту фразу - "сегодня такое то число такого то месяца" ? Опишите саму решаемую задачу подробнее, алгоритм вашего решения выглядит несколько нелепо.

Comment: @pavlofff Это написано для примера... Программа должна показать время восхода, захода и зенита солнца для нашего города... Вся это информация у меня уже есть для целого года... Мне нужно чтоб приложение вывело на экран для каждого дня эту информацию, которое я занесу заранее

Comment: Делайте дополнения к вопросу, редактируя сам вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом), а не в комментариях к нему.

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Для начала необходимо понять, что оператор `==` сравнивает ссылки на объект, а не сами объекты.

Пример:

```
Date first = new Date();
Date second = new Date();
Date third = first;

System.out.println(first == second); // false
System.out.println(first == third); // true
```

В первом случае обе ссылки указывают на разные объекты, во втором на один и тот же.

Т.к. у класса `Date` метод переопределен и выглядит так,

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();
}
```

то можно воспользоваться им. Но в вашем случае вероятность что он вернет `true` равна нулю, потому что при создании объекта через конструктор без параметров `Date()` в объекте будет хранится время в миллисекундах на момент создания объекта а метод `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` установит для года, часов, минут и секунд нули.

Пример:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
Date strDate = sdf.parse("07/3");
System.out.println(strDate.toString()); //Sat Mar 07 00:00:00 UTC 1970
```

Для получения информации о текущем дне, месяце и т.д. можно воспользоваться классом [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) у которого есть все необходимые методы, например метод [get](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)).

Для получения числа и месяца необходимо написать:

```
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = instance.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
int month = instance.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Однако следует учесть, что нумерация месяца начинается с `0`, т.е. 0 - Январь, 11 - декабрь. Поэтому лучше при сравнении пользоваться константами которые объявлены в классе и описаны в документации. Дальше вам просто надо формировать строку, которую вы хотите показать.

Ещё можно воспользоваться тем же `SimpleDataFormat` таким способом:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date())); // 07 March
```

Тут вывод зависит от текущей локализации на устройстве.

Comment: @temp вы получили текущую дату, а как его сравнить с тем что я задам?... Например я хочу сделать так чтоб пользователь видел определенный текст если сегодня 8 марта, т.е. каждый год 8 марта пользователь видит этот текст... и так для каждого дня

Answer (score 0):

Для решения вашей задачи (вывод определенного текста на каждый день в году) вам не нужно писать 365 условий на каждый день, все делается намного проще.
Создаем массивы с нужным текстом, в которые помещаем, собственно, текст для нужного дня в году. Затем выводим этот текст по номеру дня:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // массив для восходов (время восхода)
    String sunrises[] = {"7:00","6:58"};  // и тд. для всех 365 дней начиная с 1 января

    // массив для закатов (время заката)
    String sunsets[] = {"19:00","18:58"}; // и тд. для всех 365 дней начиная с 1 января

    TextView tr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSunrise);
    TextView ts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSanset);

    // получаем текущую дату
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 

    // получаем номер текущего дня в году по дате
    int numberOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    // выводим на экран информацию по восходу в этот день 
    tr.setText("Восход в " + sunrises[numberOfYear]);
    ts.setText("Закат в  " + sunsets[numberOfYear]);

}
```

Это только элементарный пример. Естественно, что вместо массива вы можете использовать любые другие коллекции с порядковыми номерами, например `ArrayList`, в котором хранить не строки, а объекты с нужной информацией, а заполнить эти массивы\коллекции вы можете любым удобным вам способом.
Так же в класс `calendar` вы можете установить любую дату и вывести данные по этой дате, а не текущей.

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров массив sunrises содержит время восходов для всех 365-ти дней через запятую. В примере только для 1 и 2 января, вам нужн продолжать его так же заполнять для всех остальных дней - в кавычках, через запятую, внутри фигурных скобок. Аналогично и для других массивов. Этот код будет работать для любого года, кроме високосного, если время восхода\заката в каждый год для одинаковых дней одинаковое. С високосным надо смотреть, какие там отличия.

Answer (score -1):

Всем спасибо. Вот что мне нужно было

```
TextView den = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.den);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

             if (day == 9 && month == 02) {
            den.setText("7:00");
        }

        if (day == 10 && month == 02) {
            den.setText("6:58");

        }
```